# Как написать сетевой клиент?

Tags: c#, .net, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте, как я могу написать сетевой клиент, которому можно было бы задать событие для действия. Например так:

```
void main() {
    MyClient client=new MyClient()
    client.receive+=my_receive;
    client.Start(9274);
}

void my_receive(byte[] data) {
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.getString(data));
}
```

Просто, все примеры, которые я нашёл, рализуют TCPClient с отправкой только одного сообщения. и сразу после этого закрываются

Comment: Головой (обычно посредством пальцев).

--

Если более серьезно, то представьте простейший чат (для консольного окна).

Клиент запускается и отправляет серверу сообщение о новом участнике.

Затем его одна часть (поток 1) читает ввод с консоли и отправляет эти строки серверу.

Другая часть (поток 2) читает строки, отправляемые сервером и выводит их на экран.

Обдумайте это. И напишите.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что getStream().read() у экземпляра TCPClient блокирует выполнение программы до того момента, пока данных нет? наподобие AcceptClient() у TCPListener.

Comment: Да. Только более правильна аналогия с Console.Read

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать следующий прием. У `NetworkStream`'а / `TCPClient`'а (в зависимости от того, что используете) есть асинхронные методы [`BeginRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread.aspx)/`EndRead`, которые возвращают управление мгновенно, а по завершении операции вызывают переданный callback-метод. В callback'е для `BeginRead` вызываете `EndRead` и следом же `BeginRead` с этим же callback'ом. Получается замкнутый круг: после завершения чтения вы снова запускаете чтение, при этом поток не блокируется. В callback'е можете дергать какой-нибудь `event`, доступный извне.

Более подробно этот прием описан, например, здесь: [Sending objects via high speed asynchronous sockets in C#](http://royalexander.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/sending-objects-via-high-speed-asynchronous-sockets-in-c-serialization-socket-programming/).